# What advantage do I get from attaching something to my house card?

Tags: game-of-thrones-card-game

In Game of Thrones The Card Game, some cards say that they can be played as an attachment to the house card instead of being played as a location. What are the advantages to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way makes it an attachment, the other makes it a location.  Which way you would want to play it depends on what your opponent is likely to be able to do.  If they can discard attachments (such as with the card [Bought and Paid For](http://www.cardgamedb.com/index.php/GoTCards.html/_/a-tale-of-champions/the-grand-melee/bought-and-paid-for-tgm)), you would want to play it as a location.  If they can get rid of locations, play it as an attachment.

The choice just makes the card flexible.